# Apache error with Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I installed XAMPP and had the UAC error when it was installed, so I installed it on a different drive, but now whenever I try to start Apache I get this error.

```
[Mon Aug 17 18:13:12.648796 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7380:tid 528] AH01909: 
www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which
matches the server name

[Mon Aug 17 18:13:13.075852 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7380:tid 528] AH01909:
www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which 
matches the server name
```

Don't know how to fix this at all

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

Install VirtualBox + lightweight Linux, and then install LAMP server. Better than XAMPP.